# Getting NULL on BelongsTo Relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

First of all, I'm a beginner to Laravel. So in the image above if I do a dump of the car variable that takes data from both the Car model and Gallery model based on an id, it returns all of that. However, if I say $car->gallery_photo, which is in the Gallery model, it returns null.

I have already put the foreign key in both of the models [belongsTo() and hasMany()]. Why am I not accessing the relations object? What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I'm typing from my phone, so at time of posting I could not show code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I solved the issue. To access the results from Gallery model I looped through $car->gallery. It was that simple lol.

Comment: meanwhile i was typing this in comments -> Wouldn't it be something like $car->Gallery->gallery_photo? aha

Comment: @Lucasjm Lol I'm dumb. It's always the simplest things that trip me up.